# ggplot2 geom_rect graph small trouble

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a `geom_rect` graph but I'm having some issues. This is my code:

```
my_dat <- data.frame(xmin = c(0, 2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 5, 2, 0.1, 0, 0 ), 
                     xmax = c(0, 10, 1, 0, 5, 10, 10, 2, 0, 0), 
                     ymin=c(10, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     ymax = c(20,20, 20, 15, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     fill = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "H", "I"))

library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(my_dat,(aes(alpha=1/3))) + 
      geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin -1 , xmax = xmax, 
                                    ymin = ymin -1, ymax = ymax, fill = fill))
g
```

and this is what I'm ending up with.

[image]

The problem is that I'm not able to fix the values, as I couldn't find a way to make the squares fit in because I'm not sure how to reposition the coordinate system other than using `"ymin -1"` and `"xmin -1"` and it's messing with the positioning.

Also I'm having trouble with the labelling in both axis, and that `alpha=1/3` showing in the legends.

Comment: what's the issue? it looks like it's plotting what you had in the data

Comment: I was trying to move the coordinate system itself, not the position of the squares, as of right now I am getting the coordinate system that I want, but the squares are moving they're value -1 from the data. I'm breaking my head trying to make them align with the 0 in both axis while still having it show below zero along both axis. It's propably an easy fix but since i'm just a beginner i'm not finding the answer. Thanks for the response by the way!

Comment: your code changes the values of the data as they are plotted. If you want to change the coordinates (i.e. "zoom in/out", then add + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(x1,x2), ylim=c(y1,y2)` and fill in your boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are passing different coordinates to ggplot than you think you do?

Is this what you intended:

```
d <- data.frame(xmin = c( 0,  2, 0.1,  0, 0.1,  5,  2, 0.1, 0, 0),
                ymin = c( 0, 10,   1,  0,   5, 10, 10,   2, 0, 0), 
                xmax = c(10, 10,  10,  5,   0,  0,  0,   0, 0, 0),
                ymax = c(20, 20,  20, 15,  20,  0,  0,   0, 0, 0),
                fill = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"))

ggplot(d) + geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill))
```

It gives rectangles that stay nicely within the (0,0)-(10,20) region.

[image]

As for the alpha value, maybe something like this helps:

```
ggplot(d) + geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill),
                      alpha = 1/3)
```

It results in

[image]

---

Ok, Using as base I managed to plot the data that I wanted:

```
d <- data.frame(xmin = c( -0.1,  2, 0.1,  -0.2, 0.1,  5,  2, 0.1, -0.3, -0.4),
                ymin = c( 10,  10,   10,  5,   -0.1, -0.2, -0.3,  -0.4, -0.5, -0.6), 
                xmax = c(0, 10,  1,  0,   5,  10,  10,   2, 0, 0),
                ymax = c(20, 20,  20, 15,  20,  0,  0,   0, 0, 0),
                fill = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"))

ggplot(d) + geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill), alpha=1/3)
```

Just changed some values and:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've edited your answer and added my final version based on your corrections. Now I just need to figure out how to resize the "x" axis to match the "y". Again, thank you!

Comment: @Caraeda To get the same scale along x and y axis, use ggplot(d) + coord_fixed(ratio=1) + geom_rect(...)